# Setting core.editor for Git on Mac OSX

Tags: git, macos, editor, atom-editor

After setting Atom as my core editor for Git, when I then commit in Terminal I receive the error:

> /usr/local/bin/atom -n -w: /usr/local/bin/atom: No such file or directory
>   error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/local/bin/atom -n -w'.
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

From the error it seems that Atom.app isn't saved in the place that Git is looking. So I have type what I believe is the full path name:

```
git config --global core.editor " '/Applications/Atom' -n -w"
```

After this I still receive the exact same error message.

(I am new to Mac and Git, though I got all of this setup no problems on my Linux system)

Comment: Where is atom really installed? Can you run `which atom`?

Comment: When I type 'which atom' into terminal, I get nothing. Yet the application shows up in the Applications folder when using Finder.

Comment: @Mureinik From the Finder info window, the path is `Macintosh HD /Applications /Atom`

Answer (score 6):

I tried using Atom as the editor for commit messages and had no issues. The only thing I might have done differently is installing Atom using [`brew cask`](https://caskroom.github.io/) instead of manually downloading and installing:

1. `brew cask install atom` (this installed v. 1.9.9 of atom)
2. `which atom` to confirm that it is present in the path at `/usr/local/bin/atom`

[image]

3. `git config --global core.editor "/usr/local/bin/atom -n -w"` to configure atom as the default git text editor.
4. Tried a test commit which opens up atom to allow typing the commit message and waits for it to exit (thanks to the `-w` option above).

Looking at the `atom` in path, it is actually a symlink:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/atom
lrwxr-xr-x  1 az  admin  53  9 Oct 09:39 /usr/local/bin/atom -> /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh
```

Therefore, I would recommend this:

`git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh -n -w"`